# How to achieve synchronization?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have one reader class which reads the data from the shared list.

```
public class Reader {

private List<String> list;
public ListReader(List<String> list) {
    this.list = list;
    }  

public void read() {
    //reading logic
    }    
}
```

I have one more class which does the job of writing data to the list.

```
public class  Writer< {

   private List<String> list;       

   public ListWriter(List<String> list) {
         this.list = list;
   }  

   public void writeNextValue(String val) {
       // writing logic 
   }         
}
```

I have one more class which instantiate Reader and  Writer class with same  List object.

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main (String ... args){
        List<String> myList= new ArrayList<>();

         Reader reader= new Reader(mylist);
         Writer writer =  new Writer (mylist);

        // multiple reads and write statements using different threads   

      }
    }
```

Now how to synchronize above multiple read/write operation?
I want at a time only one thread can write data but multiple threads should be able to read list data.

Comment: `I want at a time only one thread can write data but multiple threads should be able to read list data.` Sounds like you want a ReadWriteLock.

Comment: @tkausl Yes but I don't know how to apply in this scenario, because reading and writing is done in a different classes

Comment: Merge the two classes together (preferrable, because it improves the encapsulation), or share a single ReadWriteLock between the two objects, just like you share the single list

Comment: @JBNizet I can not change the structure of Reader and Writer classes.

Comment: Then create a class which encapsulates (i.e. creates, and delegates to) a reader and a writer, and lock from within that class (which basically merges them both together)

Comment: If you cannot change the `Reader` and `Writer` classes and they perform a sequence of operations, then they cannot reasonably lock. You could introduce a proxy class that does the locking or subclass, if that is suitable for your restrictions. Really you want to go ahead and change those classes. You can't just retrofit locking. You want *transaction memory* for that.